# Deploy one django project with multiple app on multiple subdomains on AWS EC2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, subdomain

I have one django project which contains 2apps namely, `admin` and `api`.
The admin app is dependent on `api` app to access the models.

I have 2 subdomains like: `admin.xxxx.com` and `api.xxxx.com`.

This project is currently deployed in AWS EC2 using gunicorn + nginx.

**UPDATE**

All admin requests pass to : `some.ip.address.0:8000/admin/`,  and all api requests pass through `some.ip.address.0:8000/`

Is there any way I can point my **some.ip.address.0:8000/admin/**  to **admin.xxxx.com** and **some.ip.address.0:8000/** to **api.xxxx.com**?

**UPDATE 2:**

myproject_nginx.conf file:

```
upstream myproject_backend_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).
  server unix:/home/ubuntu/myproject_backend/myproject_backend.sock fail_timeout=0;

}

server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name admin.mydomain.in;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://13.***.***.***:8000/admin/;
    }
    location /static/ {
       alias   /home/ubuntu/myproject_backend/static/;
     }

    location /media/ {
       alias   /home/ubuntu/myproject_backend/media/;
     }

 }


server {

    listen 80;

    server_name 13.***.***.***:8000  api.mydomain.in www.api.mydomain.in;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /home/ubuntu/myproject_backend/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /home/ubuntu/myproject_backend/media/;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_redirect off;

        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://myproject_backend_server;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

myproject urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^', include('api_app.urls')),
    ...
    path('admin/', include('admin_app.urls')),

    ...

    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It opening my admin login page, but I try to login it says: /admin/admin not found on this server.

Please suggest what's wrong?

Comment: Yes you do it on nginx side follow this guid: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Ahtisham Could you please check my updated question. What is wrong there? I not able to debug the issue.

Comment: :) I think you can define multiple server modules  for that take a look at docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Comment: @Ahtisham Please review the update in nginx conf file, created a block. it doesn't work when i hit `admin.mydomain.in`, instead - `http://admin.mydomain.in:8000/admin/`. Also refer my django project urls.py file

Comment: I don't think this `some.ip.address.0:8000` is right  it should be without `.0`

Comment: I don't understand from where you want to get redirect to where ?

Comment: @Ahtisham `13.***.***.***:8000/admin` opens my admin, and other than this like: `13.***.***.***:8000/` used for all api's. I want `13.***.***.***:8000/admin` to redirecting to: `admin.mydaomain.in` and all requests of `/` like: `13.***.***.***:8000/` to point to `api.mydomain.in`, eg: a api `13.***.***.***:8000/detailslist` should now be  `api.mydomain.in/detailslist`

Comment: so you want to pass request from gunicorn  to nginx right ?

Comment: @Ahtisham Is really possible to do so? I am going somewhere wrong? Could you please explain. One Django project, having two django-apps, should be redirecting to two different subdomain. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to create a gunicorn conf file which will read request from nginx and redirect it to your app :)

Comment: When you say `proxy_pass http://13.***.***.***:8000/admin/;` that needs to be mapped to your app which can be done with Gunicorn. Its an interface between your application and the nginx.

Comment: I think second answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858674/serving-a-request-from-gunicorn would help.

Comment: Try to follow the instruction - https://bitbucket.org/soceton/control-panel/src/master/ It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you want to display an admin page when the user types this address `http://admin.mydomain.in` in their browser and this admin page is handled by your django app so you are using nginx to proxy to `http://13.***.***.***:8000/admin/` from where your admin page can be accessed.

But the problem here is that your app doesn't know how to do that. So it needs a middleman ( which in your case is Gunicorn ) that is specifically meant for this purpose. Moreover nginx cannot directly communicate with your django app simply because it was not meant to serve dynamic content.

So to fix this problem you need to configure gunicorn so that it listen to address `http://13.***.***.***:8000` to where nginx will forward the request. And then run gunicorn on this address with parameter as your app name. You can read the second answer to the post [serving a request from gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858674/serving-a-request-from-gunicorn) to configure your gunicorn file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to do that you have to point two of the domains to EC2 instance hosting your django application (or ELB if you're using one) and configure Nginx so it redirects requests from one domain to `admin` and from other to `api` path.

Comment: Could you please write a sample code for redirection. I am not able to figure the redirection process? I only have one project which have 2 apps. Where will redirection takes place?  (My admin now points to `some.ip.address.0:8000/admin` and all api calls are fired from `some.ip.address.0:8000/`)

Comment: Please refer to the https://serverfault.com/questions/832456/nginx-redirect-based-on-domain-name - here's an example on how to do rewriting/redirection based on domain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried above, and added the nginx conf in my question, could you please refer and tell what am I missing?