# Is it possible to configure ip whitelisting in gunicorn?

Tags: python, security, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app deployed in docker with gunicorn and I am getting a lot of requests from bots who look for leaks and misconfigured TLS. My docker logs are flooded with it and while I have both authentication with JWT and IP-Whitelisting implemented on flask level like this

```py
@app.before_request
def restrict_access():
    # Get the IP address of the incoming request
    client_ip = request.remote_addr
    
    # Check if the client IP is in the allowed_ips list
    if client_ip not in allowed_ips:
        abort(403)  # Return a 403 Forbidden status
```

Is there a way to do the IP whitelisting earlier in application level directly in a gunicorn config (ideally without flooding my logs)?

Or do I really have to configure a load balancer for this?

Comment: Where is your application deployed? If it's in a cloud server, a virtual network with a whitelist could be the solution here

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It is normal VPS from a hoster

Comment: Ok, in this case, using Nginx as a proxy to front-end your application might be the way here. You can apply the rules to the proxy before they hit your app

Comment: [This might be a helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859371/7867968)

Comment: Yeah thanks this is what I thought I had to do. I was just hoping there is another way directly in gunicorn.

Comment: I see what you mean, but then you are putting all of that extra load onto the webserver. Nginx or similar products are meant for this task and will make your life easier in the long run